# Excel VBA - Copy certain cells and paste next to other cells in same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that will go through my sheet and find every cell in column A that has the value "Item". Then, it will copy the entire row directly beneath the cell that has the value "Item."

What I'd like to do is this:

- Go through the sheet and find each instance of "Invoice," "Invoice Date," and "City"
- When those cells are found, copy those cells and the cells immediately to their right
- *Then* go through and find every cell in column A that has the value "Item", and paste (with transpose) the two copied cells at the next blank column of that row.
- Then I'll copy the row beneath "Item" with the code I've already written below

Here is the code I have so far, along with a few pictures of what I'd like to do.

Please bear with me as I just started learning VBA yesterday and I'm very new. I know how to do some smaller parts of this, but the whole process is still hazy to me. Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

```
' Copy rows from one workbook to another at each instance of "Item"
Dim fromBook As Workbook
Dim toBook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set fromBook = Workbooks("from.xlsm")
Set toBook = Workbooks("to.xlsm")

Dim i As Range

For Each i In fromBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000")
    Select Case i.Value
        Case "Item"
            toBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & toBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = i.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
 Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**Before:**

[image: BEFORE]

**After:**

[image: AFTER]

**Another After Option, if this is simpler:**

[image: AFTER ALTERNATIVE]

Comment: will "Invoice", "Invoice Date" and "City" always be in a small table like in your pictures? or can they also be separated?

Comment: @DirkReichel They're always in the same column. I think the format is actually "Item" followed immediately by "Invoice Date" then a blank row and then "City".

Comment: @DirkReichel Apologies, third picture had a typo. Please see updated picture.

Comment: OK, thanks... just to clarify: there is only one "block" like this and you want it (always the same) transposed after each "Item"-line, is that correct? :)

Comment: Yes, correct, that block will only show up once in the sheet, and it should transposed at the end of the row beneath each "Item" line.

Answer (score 0):

Just how I would do it (it may be not that obvious, but should be fast):

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim mainTab As Range, i As Byte, pstRng As Range, pstChk As Range

  With Workbooks("from.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1") 'get first "Item"-range
    Set mainTab = .Columns(1).Find("Item", .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, 1)
    Set mainTab = .Cells(mainTab.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)

    For i = 0 To 2 'build the first table
      .Cells.Find(Array("Invoice", "Invoice Date", "City")(i), .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, 1).Resize(1, 2).Copy
      mainTab.Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial , , , True
    Next

    Set pstRng = mainTab 
    Set mainTab = mainTab.Resize(2, 3) 'the table we will copy later on
    Set pstChk = .Columns(1).Find("Item", , xlValues, 1) 'just to check if the next "Item" is a new one

    While Intersect(pstChk, .Columns(1).FindNext(pstChk.Areas(pstChk.Areas.Count))) Is Nothing 'add all "Item"-Ranges
      Set pstRng = Union(pstRng, .Cells(Columns(1).FindNext(pstChk.Areas(pstChk.Areas.Count)).Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1))
      Set pstChk = Union(pstChk, .Columns(1).FindNext(pstChk.Areas(pstChk.Areas.Count)))
    Wend

    mainTab.Copy pstRng 'copy the first table to all "Item"-Ranges in one step
  End With

  'Copy rows from one workbook to another at each instance of "Item" by "recycling"
  With Workbooks("to.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
    pstChk.Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  End With

End Sub
```

The last part, would replace your initial macro completely.

If any questions pop up, just ask ;)